# Display a Wordpress Page on an External Site

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

Similar to posts, I'd like to know how to display a published Wordpress page on to an external site.

A client wants to use the CMS to create the content, but some content is more suited for the main site (Wordpress is installed on a subdomain).

Comment: Why dont you just import the content to the new site?

Comment: Because my client doesn't know how to do that, and they need it to be as simple as possible.

Comment: oh my dear Lord, good luck...

Answer (score 2):

Okay, solved it myself - rather easy TBH.

I'm going to be bold and say this can go in any PHP file.

```
<?php
require('WORDPRESS-INSTALL/wp-blog-header.php');

$page_data = get_page(pageID);
echo $page_data->post_content;
?>
```

The first part needs to link to the WordPress file.  PageID is the ID for the page you want to display.

Comment: get_page() is now deprecated, using get_post() instead